# transform coordinates in a QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: c++, qml, qquickitem

I want to create a plugin which is derived from `QQuickPaintedItem` where the user can pan and zoom over the painted image.

For zooming I'm using the method `setContentsScale`. Now I want to transform the anchor of the painted image, so I can panning. is there a solution for this?

greetings

Comment: The `QPainter::translate` method should do what you want in your overwrite of `QQuickPaintedItem::paint(QPainter *);`